Find and Replace in Word 365 (Delete ALL AFTER YEAR and ADD Tab)
I have a word file with a list of movie titles and their year, along with misc. text and I'd like to delete all the text appearing AFTER the title and year. I'd also like to add a tab between the movie title and the year if possible.  Is there any way to achieve this when the movie titles are all different, as are all the years? You can find an example of what I'm struggling with here.

How do you consider to recognize the name of the movie? For example 2001: A Space Odyssey 1968, where it start the year, where it end the name? Or 1984 1984?

Oh that's an excellent question! I'm not sure, but considering that there are very few numerical titles, I don't anticipate it being a problem. There are less than 25 strictly numerical titles out of almost 1k in total, so even if the solution made a mistake it wouldn't have much of an impact.

The problem is if you start searching for 4 digits (year) and strip everything after you will mess the name for these movies.

Hmmm, I wonder if there's a way to eliminate everything except JUST the movie names?
